# RTSP is the only stream working from my WOWZA streaming engine

Tags: rtsp, wowza

I have every stream type [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXGDm.png) on my wowza server.
a week ago i had it working in the wowza [test players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1347q.jpg)
now the only one that works is the RTSP in VLC 
now every stream just shows a black screen.

If i try to access the m3u8 via Safari browser i can hear the audio but no visual

Any assistance on this would be a major help.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to incompatible video, audio codec. you need to user right encoder or you can use wowza transcoder to transcode your stream (h.264 , AAC) . it will resolve your playback problem. if you are using flash media live encoder you can select h.264 encoding method, and audio codec should be aac or mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick troubleshooting steps:

1. What source encoder are you using? Can you playback the source URL on VLC as well? What codec info is displayed in VLC for the source stream? It should be one of the [supported codecs for Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine/specifications).
2. What codec info is displayed in VLC for the RTSP playback link generated by your Wowza server?
3. Do you see any [errors/warnings in the access log](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?277-How-to-troubleshoot-error-messages) when you publish and playback your HLS (m3u8) stream?

Usually, this kind of error is due to an incorrect video codec, or an encoding setting, or network saturation where the video packets are not coming through correctly. You can check what error or warning messages are being generated by tailing the access log found in logs/ folder of your Wowza installation directory.

Hope this helps.